# How to boot from a usb image?

Tags: usb, solaris, bootable

I want to boot the live cd of the latest Solaris Image (11.3), but I do not have a DVD drive, just a CD drive. I tried downloading the ISO image and making a bootable USB with it (using Rufus), but every time I tried, it gave a boot error when booting from the USB. There is a .USB image on the Solaris site though. How do I create a bootable USB with that?

Comment: By the way, your question is off-topic here. It should have been asked / be moved to unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just copy it to your unmounted USB key underlying raw device with `dd`.